# Sitecore 9.1.1 Solr suggester not returning any data

Tags: solr, upgrade

I have migration from `Sitecore 8.2` to `Sitecore 9.1.1`.

I have an issue with suggester not working after Solr migration from 5.1.0 to Solr 7.2.1.

I am not getting any suggest results back from the suggester configuration. The data is definitely getting populated in the index as I can see it using Solr web interface. I have tried all the configuration on the Solr end but I am not getting any thing back. Below is my configuration in Solr:

#### Managed-schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="suggestType" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9]" replacement=" " />
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

#### Configuration in SolrConfig.xml

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">fuzzySuggester</str>
    <!--<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str> -->
    <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str> -->
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">_content</str>
    <!-- <str name="weightField">price</str> -->
     <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">suggestType</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
    <str name="highlight">false</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy" >
      <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="suggest">true</str>
          <str name="suggest.dictionary">fuzzySuggester</str>
          <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
      </lst>
      <arr name="components">
          <str>suggest</str>
      </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Tried following direct calls to Solr in the browser:

```
https://localhost:8984/solr/search_suggestions_index_master/suggest?q=water&wt=json
Response:
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":62},
  "command":"build"}
```

and

```
https://localhost:8984/solr/search_suggestions_index_master/suggest?q=water&wt=json
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1},
  "suggest":{"fuzzySuggester":{
      "water":{
        "numFound":0,
        "suggestions":[]}}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issue. Try to remove **dictionaryImpl** param in solrConfig.

This is my working configuration to compare:

```
 <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="field">pagecontent_t</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
      <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

Comment: Worked Thanks :)